# Export object with modifier animation as gltf file

Tags: animation, modifiers, export, gltf

Is it possible to export object with modifier animation as gltf file? I have a pie chart animated with screw modifier and I wanna export it as gltf. How can I archive it?[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Comment: You'd have to "bake" it: create a different mesh for each frame, and turn each of these meshes on and off by animating the scale between 1 (when it should be visible) and 0 (when it should be invisible).

Comment: @scurest Ah so let's say it's 30 frames and I have to create 30 meshes and animate its visible. It can be done in blender but how about exporting gltf? I don't know how to bake these animations.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I wanna export **Modifier** animation as gltf. I know that gltf can't support modifiers but how can I fake it? Is there a way to do that?